# Segmentation error using merge/quicksort on C on very large arrays containing ints

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, recursion, stack

I am writing different functions that sort a list of arrays to test their efficiency, as shown below I tried implementing merge/sort with recursivity which works just fine with arrays sizes lower than 10^5 going more than that crashes and gives the code error : Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD). After some googling I realized the issue is a stack overlow meaning my stack can not hold all of the recusrion calls, tried increasing the heap size (I am on Clion)
that didnt work.
Here is the quicksort implementation :

```
int devide(int t[], int low, int high){
int devide(int t[], int low, int high){

    
    int pivot_value = t[high];

    int i = low;

    for(int j =low;j<high;j++){

        if(t[j]<=pivot_value){
            swap(&t[j],&t[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    swap(&t[i],&t[high]);
    return i;
}

void quicksort_recursion(int array[], int low, int high){

    if(low < high) {
        int pivot_index = devide(array, low, high);
        quicksort_recursion(array, low, pivot_index - 1);
        quicksort_recursion(array, pivot_index + 1, high);
    }

}

void quicksort_last(int t[], int length){
    quicksort_recursion(t,0,length-1);

}
```

And here is the merge implementation :

```
void merge_sorted_arrays(int a[], int l, int m, int r) {
    int left_length = m - l + 1;
    int right_length = r - m;

    int temp_left[left_length];
    int temp_right[right_length];

    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < left_length; i++)
        temp_left[i] = a[l + i];

    for (i = 0; i < right_length; i++)
        temp_right[i] = a[m + 1 + i];


    for (i = 0, j = 0, k = l; k <= r; k++) {
        if ((i < left_length) &&
            (j >= right_length || temp_left[i] <= temp_right[j])) {
            a[k] = temp_left[i];
            i++;
        }

        else {
            a[k] = temp_right[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}

void merge_sort_recursion(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
        merge_sort_recursion(a, l, m);
        merge_sort_recursion(a, m + 1, r);
        merge_sorted_arrays(a, l, m, r);
    }
}

void merge(int a[], int length)
{

    merge_sort_recursion(a, 0, length - 1);

}
```

I want to know if there is work around the stack overflow using recursion or if this should be implemented as an iterative function.

PS : swap(int *x, int *y) is just a function that swaps 2 elements of an array.

Comment: it's a requirement, there must be a solution no?

Comment: There is no question in your post. Edit it to ask a specific question. You have diagnosed that you are using more space for the stack than is allocated. What do you want to do about that?

Comment: edited, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Would probably help a lot to stop allocating storage for your `temp_left` and `temp_right` variables locally (allocate heap memory for this manually), but you're still going to run into the same issue w/ recursion (just later)

Comment: Put your collective in a single dynamic allocation. Baring a very complicated in-place merge alogorithm, mergesort will use N-additional-space. So just allocate it up front, then pass it along with your array, using it for your temp storage.